# How to pass variable to first child in component tree

Tags: reactjs, typescript, children

For example, I have this component:

```
<Provider>
  {children}
</Provider>
```

The children component tree looks like this:

```
<Provider>
  <DivA>
    <DivB>
      <DivC>
      </DivC>
    </DivB>
  </DivA>
</Provider>
```

I want to pass variable `num` only to `DivA`, so the nested divs won't have access to it. How?

Comment: Needs more details. Why not pass the variable `num` through props of component `DivA`?

Comment: I don't want all divs to have the option to get num from props, which is what would happen if I send it through the value of the provider and get it from props. I only want divA to have the ability to "see" this param.